# Select one or zero elements from a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am far from a mathematician. Still. I want to formally express that only 0 or 1 element of a series of sets (1...n) is selectet to form a new set.

**Example:**
I have three sets $S_1 = \{1,2,3\}$, $S_2 = \{4,5,6\}$ and $S_3 = \{7,8,9\}$.

Now I want to define the set $L$ as a set containing 0 or 1 elements from $S_1, S_2,S_3$.

**Example 1:**
Containing one element from each set: $L = \{1,5,8\}$

**Example 2:**
Containing one element from $S_2$ and $S_3$and none from $S_3$: $L = \{5,8\}$.

How can I define $L$ formally?

Comment: I think $L\in{{S_1}\times{S_2}\times{S_3}\cup{S_1}\times{S_2}\cup{S_1}\times{S_3}\cup{S_2}\times{S_3}\cup\{\}}$

Comment: @barakmanos This is not readable. I think you should just write it down, that you create a new set $L$ by chosing 0 or 1 Elements from each of the sets.

Comment: @flawr: So should I duplicate what's already written in the question?

Comment: @barakmanos, the second part was directed at the OP.

Comment: @flawr: What do you mean by "second part" and what do you mean by "directed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ sets $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$, and for simplicity let $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Moreover, let $\Omega = \bigcup_{k \in [n]}S_k$ be the collection of all the elements in $S_k$. Then you can define your set $L$ as

$$L \subseteq \Omega\ \ \text{ such that }\ \ \forall k \in [n].\ |L \cap S_k| \leq 1.$$

If you are familiar with the concept of [partial functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) you can alternatively say that $L$ is the [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of some partial function $f : [n] \rightharpoonup \Omega$ with property $f(k) \in S_k$ for any $k$ such that $f(k)$ is defined.

However, in my opinion the best solution is to define $L$ using plain words:

> Let $L$ be a subset of $\Omega$ with at most one common element with any of $S_k$, for $k \in [n]$.

Complicated formulas in most cases decrease readability, while textual definitions can be just as precise. If you are unsure, use both words and a formula, e.g.

> Let $L$ be a subset of $\bigcup_{k \in [n]}S_k$ such that it has at most one common element with any of $S_k$, for $k \in [n]$, that is, $$\forall k \in [n].\ |L \cap S_k| \leq 1.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I like it! Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

A set $L$ satisfies your criterion iff

$$\#(L \cap S_a) \in \{0, 1\} \qquad \forall a \in \{1, 2, 3\}.$$

Note that this may or may not be the behavior you have in mind when a given element in $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3$ occurs in more than one $S_a$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(L\subseteq \bigcup_iS_i\right)\ \ \land\ \ \ \forall (x,y\in L).\,\forall i.\,\left((x\in S_i)\land (y\in S_i)\implies x=y\right)$

For the second point use "there exists a unique..", $\exists!$, and the set difference, $\setminus$.

Answer (score 0):

I would use $L\in{S}\cup{S_{12}}\cup{S_{13}}\cup{S_{23}}\cup{S_{123}}$, where:

- $S=\{\}$
- $S_{12}={S_1}\times{S_2}=\{\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{1,6\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{2,6\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{3,6\}\}$
- $S_{13}={S_1}\times{S_3}=\{\{1,7\},\{1,8\},\{1,9\},\{2,7\},\{2,8\},\{2,9\},\{3,7\},\{3,8\},\{3,9\}\}$
- $S_{23}={S_2}\times{S_3}=\{\{4,7\},\{5,8\},\{6,9\},\{4,7\},\{5,8\},\{6,9\},\{4,7\},\{5,8\},\{6,9\}\}$
- $S_{123}={S_1}\times{S_2}\times{S_3}=\{\{1,4,7\},\dots,\{3,6,9\}\}$

---

Or simply $L\in\{\}\cup({S_1}\times{S_2})\cup({S_1}\times{S_3})\cup({S_2}\times{S_3})\cup({S_1}\times{S_2}\times{S_3})$